# I'm trying to print equilateral triangles side side but only one of them is correct (c language)

Tags: c

I've been stuck with this one for days and i can't figure out why only one of them is equilateral. The triangles must be equilateral and must be aligned horizontally.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int triangles, h, i, j, k;      

printf("How many triangles do you want to print: ");    
scanf("%d", &triangles);

if (triangles>4)
    printf("Up to 4 triangles only");   
else{   
    for (i=1; i<=3; i++){ 
        for (h=1; h<=triangles; h++){   
            for (j=0; j<=5-i; j++){ 
                printf(" ");
            }
            for (k=1; k<=2*i-1; k++){ 
                printf("*");
            }
        }

    printf("\n");   
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Only the first triangle was equilateral, the rest were not. Please help me. Thank you!

My output:

```
  *     *     *
 ***    ***    ***
*****   *****   *****
```

Comment: You allowed padding spaces on the *left* of each triangle's row, but not on the *right*. Just copy/paste the 'padding' loop to appear again after the 'stars' loop.

Comment: For starters I'd give the variables more meaningful names than just h, i, j and k.